# How can I refresh a view block as soon as new content is added?

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I want to refresh a views block whenever new content is added.
I am using [views auto refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh) module

> Quick HOWTO: Using a ping script
>
> Using a ping script is essential for production environments, to avoid
>   a full Drupal bootstrap at each refresh.
>
> Create a new page view Copy the file ping.php.example to your Drupal
>   root folder and rename it as ping.php Edit ping.php such that
>   DRUPAL_ROOT points to your Drupal root, and adjust the query: $result
>   = $db->query("SELECT count(nid) FROM node WHERE created > $timestamp");
>
> to reflect your view's generated SQL query. Make sure to keep the
>   created condition in the query. Add a new header of type Global:
>   Autorefresh with: Set the interval time to 5000ms Check Use a ping url
>   In Path to the ping script, enter ping.php Save the view and open its
>   page In a second browser tab, add a new content that fits the view's
>   criteria See the new content in the view!

Is there any other way we can refresh a views when content is created

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using the [Views node.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_nodejs) module

> This module implements dynamical update of views by nodejs after executing rules action.
>   This module implements rules action which we can add to any rule for updating some views (views which need update, one can select in action).
>
> During updating of views all arguments that are already passed to view will be taken into account.
>
> It is also correctly working with views which use ajax.
>   Introducing [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWD2iQB0zdg).

Comment: I will need to add node.js on the server it may need some extra efforts or is it not so

Comment: @harshal yes you need to add node.js on the sever. Ofcourse you need to put effort to achieve this. :)

Comment: any links on how to add node.js on server and integrate it with node.js drupal module?

Comment: Check the following links
[Drupal Real-Time Dashboard with Node.js](http://drupalconnect.com/blog/articles/drupal-real-time-dashboard-nodejs)

[Installation of Node.js integration module for Drupal](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1sxDaH3Z-U)

Comment: Also can we use views auto refresh for views block refresh using incremental refresh method?

Comment: @harshal I didn't use that module before. Let me try that for you. but don't expect me to give the response ;) If I've time I'll continue on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16608/discussion-between-harshal-and-krishna-mohan).

Comment: If you want the view to be refreshed when new articles/nodes are added you need to use the ping.php and adjust the query accordingly.